# Navbar does not show submenu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

How do I turn the tab UI into a dropdown menu? I have the following bootstrap navbar fixed at bottom with 2 submenu items (page 1 and page 2). But, when I click on "One" it does not show the submenu items. 
[Here](http://www.z1labs.com/tabsnavigation.html) is the page and view source code shows the style and js being used. Thank you.

```
     <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse fixed-bottom">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" name="tab1" class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">One</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">page 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" name="tab2">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" name="tab3">Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" name="tab4">Four</a></li>

        </ul>

    </nav>
```

Comment: Is that a Bootstrap menu? What version? Please add CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropup"><a href="#" name="tab1" class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">One</a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><a href="#">page 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">page 2</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" name="tab2">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="tab3">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="tab4">Four</a></li>
</ul>
```

I added `class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"` on the `<a>` tag.

Comment: dimitris, I edited to reflect your suggestion but it does change.

Comment: ok, i edited my answer. Replaced dropdown class with dropup class in "li" parent element. Now it should work.

Comment: Did it solve your problem? If so, feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: If you click the link to the page and view source you will see I have the same as your suggestion but it does not work :(

Comment: ok, found your problem. Remove "overflow: hidden;" from #tab css style. I tried on your source and worked.